# Batch commit been called before batch finishes

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting "Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed." in this snippet of code. Although, I'm sure why `batch.commit()` is not waiting for the `forEach` finishes.

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const batch = db.batch();

const channelIds = [];

const messages = data
    .map((item) => {
        if (!item || !item.phone_number)
            return null;

        const msg = pupa(message, item);

        if (!channelIds.includes(item.channel.id))
            channelIds.push(item.channel.id);

        return {
            ...item,
            message: msg
        };
    })
    .filter((msg) => msg);

logger.info(`Creating messages/${messageId}/sms entries. [Count = ${messages.length}]`);

// From all channels included in the messages array, it fetchs its remaining sms credits.
channelIds.forEach(async (channelId) => {
    const subscriptionDetails = (await admin.firestore()
        .collection('channels')
        .doc(channelId)
        .collection('subscription')
        .doc('details')
        .get()).data();

    const creditsRemaining = subscriptionDetails.limits.snapshot.sms_notifications - subscriptionDetails.limits.used.sms_notifications;

    // Sends messages according to its respective channel ID and channel remaining credits.
    messages
        .filter((item) => item.channel.id === channelId)
        .slice(0, creditsRemaining)
        .forEach((msg) => {
            batch.set(db.collection('messages')
                .doc(messageId)
                .collection('sms')
                .doc(), {
                phone_number: msg.phone_number,
                message: msg.message
            });
        });
});

await batch.commit();
```

EDIT: I fixed this issue by wrapping the `forEach` in a Promise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing an `await` before `batch.set(db.collection('messages')...`, which means that your `await batch.commit()` gets run before all `batch.set()` calls have completed.

Comment: I fixed this issue by wrapping the `forEach` in a Promise. Thanks anyways!

Comment: That's great to hear @RenatoGuimaraesNunes   You might want to post that (with the updated code) as a self-answer.